# Issue with using PriorityQueue.contains( ) in java

Tags: java, collections

I was testing the functionality of Min-PriorityQueue in Java. This is how I implemented it. But at runtime, .contains() return false for an object, I believe is present in the data-structure. Any insights where this is going wrong ?

```
    public class NodeStruct implements Comparable<NodeStruct>{

        public String FName;
        public String LName;
        public int age;

        public NodeStruct(String fname, String lName, int age){
            this.FName = fname;
            this.LName = lName;
            this.age = age;
        }
        @Override
        public int compareTo(NodeStruct that) {
            return (this.age - that.age);
        }


        public boolean equals(NodeStruct obj){
            return (obj.age == this.age && obj.FName.equals(this.FName) && obj.LName.equals(this.LName));
        }

        public void print(){
            System.out.println("FName, LName, age : " + this.FName + "," + this.LName + "," + this.age);
        }

    }



    import java.util.*;
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.io.*;

    /* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
    public class Main
    {

        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {


            PriorityQueue<NodeStruct> PQ = new PriorityQueue<NodeStruct>(5);

            NodeStruct tmp = new NodeStruct("Harry", "Potter", 15);
            PQ.offer(tmp);

            tmp = new NodeStruct("Ron", "Weasley", 14);
            PQ.offer(tmp);

            tmp = new NodeStruct("Hermione", "Granger", 16);
            PQ.offer(tmp);



            boolean isPresent = PQ.contains(new NodeStruct("Ron", "Weasley", 14));

            System.out.println("Is Present : " + isPresent);

            NodeStruct tmp2 = PQ.peek();
            tmp2.print();


        }

    }
```

The output shows :

```
          Is Present : false
          FName, LName, age : Ron,Weasley,14
```

Comment: Yet another possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Also, not overriding `hashCode` with `equals` is a **big** no no. Override `hashCode`.

Comment: edited the code to replace == with .equals() but the issue doesn't get resolved by this quick fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should explicitly override `equals()` method with an `Object` parameter. Your `equals()` method is not an overridden version of `Object#equals()`, it is an overloaded version. And Java collections call `equals()` on their operations, and `super.equals()` is called in your case, not your implementaton.

**Edit:**

Now I also checked your `equals()` implementation besides signature. Use `equals()` for the comparison of String fields, not `==` operator.

Comment: Dont forget to use `equals` method for string comparison not `==`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, you must also have consistency in the `compareTo` and `equals` methods in order to correctly implement the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface:

> The natural ordering for a class C is said to be consistent with equals if and only if e1.compareTo(e2) == 0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 of class C. Note that null is not an instance of any class, and e.compareTo(null) should throw a NullPointerException even though e.equals(null) returns false.

For example:

```
NodeStruct n1 = new NodeStruct("Harry", "Potter", 15);
NodeStruct n2 = new NodeStruct("Hermione", "Granger", 15);

// n1.compareTo(n2) == 0
// but
// n1.equals(n2) == false
```

Because of this inconsistency, these objects will not behave as expected in any ordered Collection.  You may want to change the `compareTo` method to use lexicographical ordering on the name fields when two nodes have the same age.

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly override equals() method.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object that){
    NodeStruct obj = (NodeStruct) that;
    return (obj.age == this.age && obj.FName.equals(this.FName) && obj.LName.equals(this.LName));
}
```